# How to attach two or more files to SEND action on Android

Tags: android, email

I would send two or more files using ACTION_SEND on Android as an excerpt below:

> Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>   emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
>   "pokus"); 
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
>   "t" ); 
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
>
> **emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
>   Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file1.jpg"));**
>
> **emailIntent.putExtra(**android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
>   Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file2.jpg"));**
>
> startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
>   "Send mail..."));

But that code does not work with GMail, it attaches only the last file. Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's impossible using GMail.

If you want to programmaticly send email manually (skipping the GMail client), then you could attach as many items as you want, using android-javamailer:

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android