# Debugging Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, push, android-c2dm

I am using [C2dm](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) for push notification and as per [these instructions](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#implementation)

we got at last response code 200
but not get notification on device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.2).

what will be the reason for that ?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint where you create the notification and test if your code gets to that point. If not, backtrack until you find the error. Log messages are also useful for this

Comment: Hi,
i m trying it but not able to find error till now....
is it any way to get error?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you're getting an error, copy it and edit it into your original question.

Comment: Reciving OK as responsemessage and responsecode is 200.
but not getting push .

Comment: Reciving OK as responsemessage and responsecode is 200.
but not getting push .
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append("Email=").append(email);
  builder.append("&Passwd=").append(password);
  builder.append("&accountType=GOOGLE");
  builder.append("&source=testNotification");
  builder.append("&service=ac2dm");

in source what we need to write package name or project name?

Comment: Hi Craigy,

Problem solved.
This problem is occurred due to firewall( WIFI),nothing else.
Thanks for help

Comment: @MSingh: if the problem is solved, answer your own question and accept. That's the SO way.

Comment: i hope this code help u 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338887/how-to-attach-two-or-more-files-to-send-action-on-android

Comment: @M Singh what exactly was your problem.actually im also facing the same issue.what has to be done.my pc also behind a corporate firewall but is is a static machine.kindly help

Comment: Actully it was cum due firewall,u can check ur code with doungle(any of ur private network).

Comment: @MSingh Actullay i have tried in everything, PC with Ethernet(Not over a corporate n/w) and a PC with Tata photon USB Modem!! Push never reached my phone as well as emulator, but receiving http status 200 response. What should i do now, any idea??

Comment: Ok then install Google Chrome to Phone Extension,and share text from it ,this is for chacking that all other push is coming or not . If push  "Google Chrome to Phone Extension" is coming on ur phone then there is an error in ur code otherwise something going wrong with network..

Comment: @MSingh May i know in which device u have tested. Because if i try to install it from android market. It says "This item cannot be installed in your device's country." Tried in almost all android devices